# Call an oracle db procedure using php

Tags: php, oracle

I need to setup a connection with an oracle db in order to call an oracle based procedure. In order to setup the connection, I have followed the following method.

```
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST 
    = 172.25.16.140)(PORT = xxxx)))((CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)
            (UR=A)))" ;


    $db_username = "xxxx";
    $db_password = "xxxx";
    try{
        $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$db,$db_username,$db_password);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
    }
```

This is giving me the error:

```
cannot find drivers
```

Any solution for this will be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to add the drivers to your PHP installation.

Comment: I have uncommented php_pdo_mysql.dll in php.ini file and restart apache as per some searches through google. But it didn't help. :(

Comment: I have checked phpinfo details and Pdo Drivers enabled for "mysql", "pgsql", "sqlite".

Comment: Did that get rid of the error? If not, make sure you're editing the right php.ini file.